# Get list of fields and widgets from django form

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.9, to build a highly customised system.  Part of this means that I have to extract the list of fields and their related widgets from a great many forms.

for example, from something like this:

```
from django import forms
class PortfolioForm(forms.Form):
    organisation_id = forms.IntegerField(label='organisation_id', required=True)
    portfolio_id = forms.IntegerField(label='portfolio_id', required=False)
    portfolio_name = forms.CharField(label='portfolio_name', max_length=50, required=True)
```

I'd expect to be able to get a list of tuples or lists like so:

```
(
    (organisation_id, <widget_name>),
    (portfolio_id, <widget_name>),
    (portfolio_name, <widget_name>)
)
```

The DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass mixin seems to block this being taken from the `.fields` attribute

Any ideas how to do this? Or is it better to extract via the template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
form = PortfolioForm()
tuple((field_name, form.fields[field_name].widget.__class__) for field_name in form.fields)
```

Within methods you can change `form.` on `self.`

Comment: got it. I was acting on the class, rather than an instance